# Using promises on Node.js on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

How does one use promises on Node.js running on Windows? For the life of me I can't seem to get any example to work...

For example something like this doesn't work:

```
var pinput = new Promise(
   function(fulfillPromise, breakPromise) {
     var btn = document.getElementById("button");
     var txt = document.getElementById("txt");
     btn.onclick = function() {
       fulfillPromise(txt.value);
     }
   }
);

pinput.whenOnly(function(value) { alert(value); });
```

Throwing in requires doesn't help either:

```
Promise = require('promise');
```

All I get is either:

```
ReferenceError: promise is not defined
```

or

```
Error: Cannot find module 'Promise'
```

And I can't seem to find the promise from the latest API either...  (http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/)

Me be puzzled.

Comment: Are you sure a promise module is actually included in the Node.js core? I believe it is not. Perhaps you want a library like https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe promises were removed. [See this Google Groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/msg/0c483b891c56fea2) for more information.

Comment: Ah, so for concurrent functions (everyone needs to be done in order to move on) one is forced to hack their own solution?

Comment: I would just download a library that includes this functionality.